# Regex uppercase words with condition

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex and I can't figure it out how to do this:

> Hello this is JURASSIC WORLD shut up Ok
>
> [REVIEW] The movie BATMAN is awesome lol

What I need is the title of the movie. It will be only one per sentence. I have to ignore the words between [] as it will not be the title of the movie.

I thought of this:

```
^\w([A-Z]{2,})+
```

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use negative look arounds to ensure that the title is not within `[]`

```
\b(?<!\[)[A-Z ]{2,}(?!\])\b
```

- `\b` Matches word boundary.
- `(?<!\[)` Negative look behind. Checks if the matched string is not preceded by `[`
- `[A-Z ]{2,}` Matches 2 or more uppercase letters.
- `(?!\])` Negative look ahead. Ensures that the string is not followed by `]`

**Example**

```
>>> string = """Hello this is JURASSIC WORLD shut up Ok
... [REVIEW] The movie BATMAN is awesome lol"""
>>> re.findall(r'\b(?<!\[)[A-Z ]{2,}(?!\])\b', string)
[' JURASSIC WORLD ', ' BATMAN ']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it. Just out of curiosity, why does it take also whitespaces?

Comment: @Eric Because I added space in `[A-Z ]{2,}`. You can use `strip()` later on to remove the spaces.